# Excel: Commonality between comma separated cells in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to list all values from a column of cells that contain comma separated values that share a Commonality - EG

For example I want move user1 from on thing to another – to do so I have to move the users and groups they’re members along with any other user who is a member of the same group.

I would also have to identify any other groups those users were also members of and so on.

So User1 is a member of  Group1 and so is User2 – User2 is a member of Group2 and so is User9 but user9 is also a member of group8.

I would need to identify all users that are a member of Groups 1,2,8 because they would have a dependency on each other.

So based on that i want to see all of the group numbers that would potentially need to be identified as a result of moving each user - if that makes sense?

as in below example:

| User | Group Numbers | Answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User2 | 1 ; 2 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User3 | 2 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User4 | 3 ; 4 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User5 | 5 | 5 ; 6 ; 10 ; 11 |
| User6 | 6 | 5 ; 6 ; 10 ; 11 |
| User7 | 7 ; 2 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User8 | 7 ; 4 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User9 | 8 ; 2 | 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 7 ; 8 |
| User10 | 9 | 9 |
| User11 | 10 ; 6 ; 5 | 5 ; 6 ; 10 ; 11 |
| User12 | 11 ; 5 | 5 ; 6 ; 10 ; 11 |

having a little difficulty figuring out a formula or reasonable way of doing this

The list is quite a long list too..

thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you need to define the problem more precisely. As your Q reads right now, there is no clear "common factor" in your second paragraph of text; user 1 stands alone outside the commonality of user 2 and 9 having group 2. NOTE: Using Autofilter you can select users (leaving only them, visible) by filtering for "2" in the group column...

Comment: Have updated the question to try and explain the question a little better... thanks

Comment: Because User7 is a member of Group2 and Group7 - User8 is also a member of Group7 - filtering on "2" would miss User8

Comment: If I understand the problem frame, it seems the answers have to be mutually exclusive. So I see 3 tasks: 1) building out that mutually exclusive answer list (I think the most difficult of the 3 steps), 2) mapping individual numbers to the answer list, 3) putting a lookup formula in your Answer column that would take the first individual number in your Group Numbers list and return the answer from 2).

Comment: To build that mutually exclusive answer list I would probably start with the the group numbers with the most numbers in a group and work backwards through smaller number sets until you exhausted all the numbers. If it's any comfort, your answer set can't be more than the total indiviidual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not designed to work with sets, rather with sequences, but there are no internal functions here either.
In the new Excel, thanks to the `LAMBDA` function, you can define your own functions, and in this case you can use such auxiliary functions.
We will define 3 functions:

1. A function called `union` for creating the sum of sets (preserving the order of the elements) – it works on the principle of combining texts and removing duplicates.

   =LAMBDA(a, b, TEXTJOIN(" ; ", , UNIQUE(--TEXTSPLIT(a & ";" & b, ";"), TRUE)))
2. A function called `sepd` that returns a Boolean value `TRUE` if 2 strings do not have elements in common – the function compares the strings simply concatenated to the union.

   =LAMBDA(a, b, TEXTJOIN(" ; ", , a, b) = union(a, b))
3. A function called `lsort` that is used to sort the elements of a list.

   =LAMBDA(a, TEXTJOIN(" ; ", , IFERROR(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(a, ";"), , , TRUE), "")))

The formula used to find dependent items looks at a list of group numbers and appends all related items to the sequence. Because the order of the data is random, you should go through the list several times until you get consistent results.
I used this formula (in E59):

```
=REDUCE(B59, $B$59:$B$70, LAMBDA(a, b, IF(sepd(a, b), a, union(a, b))
```

I repeated the calculations in the following columns until the result was the same.
Finally, in column `M`, I used the `lsort` function to sort the results.
[image: groups]